# How to mount a NAS during boot?

Tags: boot, automount, nas

I'm trying to mount a NAS drive USB connected to my Netgear 4300 router with NO password using 14.04.
I have tried several options in the fstab file (including the ones here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently).
Some of them don't work at all (device doesn't exist.etc...). The closest I get to make it work with fstab as

```
//192.168.1.1/readyshare/nas /media/nas cifs       user=user,uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev,auto,noperm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,umask=000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,rw    0   0
```

The results of `sudo mount -a` = Password for `user@//192.168.1.1/readyshare/nas`:
What gives and where else can I find more info, please?
I can get to all the folders using "Files".

Comment: Can you please clarify the issue you are having when you give the `sudo mount -a` command?  If you can access the share, what is the problem?

Comment: Thk u Muru.
I was able to resolve the issue thanks to a link to mount.cifs (nothing better than reading the Manual). Sudo mount -a would return "provide password to 192.168.1.1....(none is needed). Here is the final line that worked. //192.168.1.1/nas /media/nas cifs       guest,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,rw    0   0

Answer (score 0):

For the Netgear folks with w Readyshare folder.
the final line in the fstab file that worked:

```
//192.168.1.1/nas /media/nas cifs guest,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,rw 0 0
```